# VLC-QT get the framerate of current video file

Tags: libvlc, vlc-qt

I use the `vlc-qt lib` and try to access the frames per second information of an openend video file.

The player:

```
_instance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args(), this);
_player = new VlcMediaPlayer(_instance);
_media = new VlcMedia(file, true, _instance);
_player->openOnly(_media);
```

the player has a public function `playbackRate()` but it gives only the current playback ration, so it is 1 if no slowmotion is applied.

```
float playbackRate = _player->playbackRate();
```

I also tried to get it over the codec, but the codec itself is not a class but only an enum with possible codecnames.

**How can I access the fps, so get back something like 30 frames per second?**

Answer (score 0):

Using python vlc.py:
Where self.player is:

```
self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()
```

It has a function `get_fps()`

```
def mspf(self):# Milliseconds per frame.
    return int(1000 // (self.player.get_fps() or 25))
```

EDIT:
Having dug deeper, there appears to be no reference to `fps` in the vlc-qt sources, except where it offers fps as an experimental input to the `Media::duplicate` and `Media::record` functions within VlcMedia.cpp although fps is available within vlc